# Counting specific string in a text file corresponding to it's country

Tags: text-processing, awk, osx

I have a text file, with fields separated by a tab, containing:

```
Baseball        Korea
Badminton       Spain            
Soccer          Germany
Baseball        Korea
Badminton       Spain
Badminton       Korea
```

And what I'm trying to do is count a specific sport with its country. For example i want to look up badminton so it will produce

```
Korea   2
Spain   3
```

I'm using an awk script to do so but I'm having trouble with the count

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = '\t'} {for country in $2) if ($1 ==   
'Badminton') count [$1]++} END {print (country), count 
[$1]}' Sport.txt
```

Comment: @roaima Mac os x terminal

Comment: I don't understand since `Badminton` appears only `1` time for `Korea`.  In that case the solution is quite straight forward: `awk '$1 == "Badminton" { c[$2]++; } END {for (a in c) print a,c[a]}' sports.txt`

Comment: @val0x00ff each column is separated by tabs. In this case should I add it before the $1 clause in your command?

Comment: no but you can use this `awk '$1 == "Badminton" { c[$2]++; } END {for (a in c) print a,c[a]}' OFS='\t' sports.txt` where you specify that the `Output Field Seperator` is a tab.

Comment: @val0x00ff that ought to be an answer rather than just written in comments.

Comment: @roaima you are right but you guys already answered the question, so I'm not sure if my answer has any added value.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
$ awk 'x==$1{a[$2]++;}END{for(i in a){print i, a[i];}}' x='Badminton' file
Korea 1
Spain 2
```

If first column value is 'Badminton', increment the counter in the associative array. And at the end of the file, print the array contents.

Comment: I'm getting an error awk: can't open file x. How is it so?

Comment: @Maxxx you didn't specify OSX so Guru used a `gawk` construct (like I did). Use `awk -v x=Badminton '...code...' file` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

This will achieve your stated aim

```
awk -v sport=Badminton -F $'\t' '$1 == sport { country[$2]++ } END { for (c in country) { printf "%s\t%d\n", c, country[c] } }' Sport.txt
```

Results using your example `Sport.txt` file

```
Korea   1
Spain   2
```

Explanation

```
# Set the awk variable 'sport' and the field separator as a tab, and read the file
awk -v sport=Badminton -F $'\t' '...code...' Sport.txt

# If the first field matches, increment the count for this country
$1 == sport { country[$2]++ }

# When there is no more input, print out each country and its count
END { for (c in country) { printf "%s\t%d\n", c, country[c] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply.

```
grep Badminton <(uniq -c <(sort infile))
1 Badminton         Korea
2 Badminton         Spain
```

- First `sort` the `infile` file.
- Then `uniq` and print each lines and their duplicated counts.
- Last do the `grep` for pattern as `Badminton`.